# SERVER_NAME returns www as subdomain

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, mobile, hook

What I want to do is to create same copy of my CodeIgniter based web site as a mobile site. It's url is supposed to be like `m.example.com`.

As I mentioned before in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928677/mobile-version-of-site-using-codeigniter), I used hooks for redirection. Now I have another problem. After checking whether user agent is mobile or not by using HTTP_USER_AGENT, I redirect `www.example.com` to `m.example.com` by using php header function. Altough I redirect, when I print the `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` in m.example.com, it still seems like `www.example.com`. What is wrong in here? My hooks code is like below:

```
class Mobile
{
public function isMobile()
{
    $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    if(preg_match('/android.+mobile|Android 4.1.1|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
    {
        $fullUrl = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        $fullUrl = str_replace('http://', '', $fullUrl);

        if(substr($fullUrl, 0, 3) == 'www')
        {
            $fullUrl = 'http://' . str_replace('www', 'm', $fullUrl);
            header("Location:" . $fullUrl);
            exit;
        }
        if(substr($fullUrl, 0, 3) == 'new')
        {
            $fullUrl = 'http://m.' . $fullUrl;

            header("Location:" . $fullUrl);
        }
        else if(substr($fullUrl, 0, 4) == 'beta')
        {
            $fullUrl = 'http://m.' . $fullUrl;

            header("Location:" . $fullUrl);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `www` **is** as subdomain.

Comment: @DainisAbols what do you mean? Can you explain it clearly?

Comment: @OnurGöker http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain

Comment: @DainisAbols I know what subdomain is. This is not a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the problem. Problem is in index.php file. When I change index.php file as default.php, problem is solved.

Another solution is to define m subdomain in nginx server.